# Can I use Athena / Presto to sort a table before writing?

Tags: parquet, amazon-athena, presto

I want to archive my logs into the Parquet format.  Before writing the table, I want to sort it by a column `c` so that each Parquet file will only have a small range of `c`.  That will allow Athena / Presto to efficiently scan the table when a query includes a WHERE clause on column `c` (via predicate pushdown).

However, it's unclear to me whether I can use Athena or Presto to sort the entire table.  I need a distributed sort - not one that takes place on a single node - because the dataset is too big to fit on a single node.  Is such a sort possible?  If so, how to I invoke it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presto supports [distributed sort](https://trino.io/docs/current/admin/dist-sort.html) [since 0.206](https://trino.io/docs/current/release/release-0.206.html).
Athena is [currently based on Presto 0.172](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/release-note-2018-01-19.html) and I don't know if they backported this feature.

So your choices are

- grab latest Presto @ https://trino.io/download.html
- get easy to deploy Presto on AWS from Starburst (https://www.starburstdata.com/presto-aws-cloud/) (disclaimer: I am from Starburst)
- use Presto bundled on EMR (I don't know how it comes configured, but probably Distributed Sort is still enabled by default)

Comment: wait, does this really get around the memory constraints of the previous presto sorts?  From what here (https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/admin/dist-sort.html), all the data still ends up on a single node.  The 'distributed' part of the sort is just that some pre-sorting takes place in a distributed manner before all the data ends up on one node.

Comment: The final merge sort is done on a single node, but it is done in a streaming fashion (think: merge part of the merge sort algorithm). Compare this to non-distributed sort where whole data is kept in single node's memory before it is sorted (also in memory).

Comment: thanks for the clarification.  If you add that to the answer and basically say 'there is no way to do this in a fully distributed (and hence scalable) manner in presto' then I will accept your answer.

Comment: In the question you have "... because the dataset is too big to fit on a single node" -- this limitation is removed when using distributed sort, because distributed sort is scalable in terms of memory usage. I agree that it is not scalable in terms of processing time.

Comment: ah, I think I've misunderstood how the streaming nature of the mergesort gets around the memory issue.  if it gets around the memory bottleneck then yes, this is a solution to the problem I laid out.  I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Athena engine version 2 (released Nov 13, 2020) appears to now support the distributed `ORDER BY` feature of Presto:

[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/engine-versions-reference.html#:~:text=engine%20version%202.-,Query%20Performance,-Bucketed%20tables%20%E2%80%93%20Improved](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/engine-versions-reference.html#:%7E:text=engine%20version%202.-,Query%20Performance,-Bucketed%20tables%20%E2%80%93%20Improved)

> ORDER BY – ORDER BY operations are now distributed by default, enabling larger ORDER BY clauses to be used.